How to apply a function f to the output of external language cell?
I have a External language session of "SQL-JDBC" created and connected to the External language cell:
StartExternalSession[{"SQL-JDBC","Target"->SQLConnection[...],"ReturnType"->"NamedRows"}]

By default the "ReturnType"->"Dataset". I have changed it to "NamedRows" so I can use a custom function f to format the output.
How do I make it apply the function f before outputting the result from the "ExternalLanguage" cell that is using this ExternalSeessionObject. I looked at the option for StartExternalSession called "Epilog". But how do I pass it the output of the query?
Can CellEpilog function apply a function to the output of the cell?

Nevermind I was able to find a way to do it.
SetOptions[NextCell[CellStyle->"ExternalLanguage"],{CellProlog:>($Post=f),CellEpilog:>($Post=.)}]

So my question now narrows down to how do I target only those "ExternalLanguage" whose CellEvaluationLanguage->"SQL-JDBC".
Second how do I apply it to any cells in the entire notebook where they already exist or will exist. So when they are created they come with the new CellProlog and CellEpilog options defined if they are cells of CellStyle->"ExternalLanguage" and CellEvaluationLanguage->"SQL-JDBC". This question has turned into a notebook question now so I will add more tags.
